# How do I know if I in the middle of key series in vim?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

Perhaps I wasn't very clear in the title.
What I'm searching for is a way to map the `f` key to execute some command, but only if I'm not in the middle of another series of a key strokes like `cf<char>` or `df<char>`.

Is there a way to know that?

Thanks a lot!

(I've searched this site and didn't find similar question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cf<char>` and other *operator+motion* scenarios, Vim enters a special mode after the operator, "operator-pending mode", in which mappings created for other modes don't apply.

Therefore, you could map `f` in normal mode without impacting its behavior in operator-pending mode:

```
nnoremap f <Cmd>echo 'foo'<CR>
```

That said, `f` is a useful command in its own right so it might not be a good idea to override it with something unrelated. Also, `f` in normal mode and `f` in operator-pending mode have the same semantics. By changing the meaning of one `f`, you make the other `f` less useful.

Comment: I can't stress this point enough, please think about mapping your custom stuff to `<leader> f` not `f` itself, it is really useful!!
 
P.S. @romainI hate it when you are faster than I am.

Comment: Thanks you! I'm mapping to something that does exactly what `f` does plus something else.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo let's split: you take the odd-numbered weeks and I take the even-numbered ones ;-).

Comment: @romainl I would love to, but in this case I have to take a humble bow in front of your knowledge and nourish myself with the leftovers :D